# Why can't I capture AWS EC2 CLI Output in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, aws-cli

I am trying to capture the output of an `aws ec2 delete-snapshot` in a Bash script command but I cannot get anything to capture the output. I have tried `result=$(command)`, `` result=`command` `` etc. but when I try to echo `$result` there is nothing there.

Here is some example output.

```
root@host:~# aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid --output json>test

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (vid) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
root@host:~# aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid>test

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (vid) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
root@host:~# cat test
root@host:~# testing=$(aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid)

A client error (InvalidParameterValue) occurred when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (vid) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
root@host:~# echo $testing

root@host:~#
```

I need to automate creation and deletion of snapshots, but I can't capture the output.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `>` operator only redirects `stdout` ("standard output"), or "file descriptor `1`". Error messages are usually printed on a different file descriptor, `2`, `stderr`, ("standard error").  On your terminal screen, you are seeing both `stdout` and `stderr`.

The `>` operator is really more just a shortcut for `1>`, and again, only redirects `stdout`. The `2>` operator is similar to `1>` but it instead of redirecting `stdout`, it redirects `stderr`.

```
user@host$ echo hello world >/dev/null
user@host$ echo hello world 1>/dev/null
user@host$ echo hello world 2>/dev/null
hello world
user@host$
```

So, to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file, use `>file 2>&1`.

```
user@host$ echo hi 2>/dev/null 1>&2
user@host$
```

This says, "redirect the echo's `stderr` to `/dev/null`, and redirect `stdout` to stderr.

```
user@host$ curl --invalid-option-show-me-errors >/dev/null
curl: option --invalid-option-show-me-errors: is unknown
try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

user@host$ curl --invalid-option-show-me-errors 2>/dev/null
user@host$ 
user@host$ curl --invalid-option-show-me-errors >/dev/null 2>&1
user@host$
```

In modern Bash, you can also use `&>` to redirect both streams to the same file:

```
user@host$ curl --invalid-option-show-me-errors &>/dev/null
user@host$
```

So for you, specifically, use:

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid --output json >test 2>&1
```

Or

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid --output json &>test
```

Answer (score 5):

Error output will be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and you are only redirecting `stdout`. If you want to capture `stderr` as well, you need to add `2>&1`, e.g.:

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid --output json >test 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to capture both stdout and stderr in a variable, try:

```sh
RESULT="$(aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id vid --output json 2>&1)"

if ! [[ $RESULT =~ "Successfully deleted snapshot" ]]; then
  echo "ERROR while deleting snapshot"
  echo "$RESULT"
  exit 1
fi

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue as well when I tried to insert an ACW CLI output into a variable. What I did to overcome this issue was:

```
token=$(aws <command> | jq -r '.NextToken')
echo $token
```